# Why do I get a warning when trying to update parent from child component in React Native and what to do about it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a component called LoginScreen which returns some child components, among them “EmailInput” and “PasswordInput”. These two child components are styled in a certain way and also responsible for checking (using Regex) if the input is a valid email (in terms of the format) and the password is at least 8 characters otherwise they will individually render a “HelperText” component which is from a library called “react-native-paper” where they display an error message reflecting the malformed email or short password.
Each of these components also sets a state(through passing it as a prop)  in the parent component (LoginScreen) which says that the password and/or email has a valid or invalid format so that the login button is enabled/disabled based on the validity.

```
const EmailInput = props => {
const isEmailValid = () => {
   if (props.value != '') {
     var isValid = isValidEmail(props.value);
     props.notifyIfEmailIsValid(isValid);
     return isValid;
   } else {
     // parent component will consider empty value as not valid
     props.notifyIfEmailIsValid(false);
     // this component will treat empty value as valid, and do not show error message
     return true;
   }
 };
```

Researching into the warning leaves me thinking that the last section is the problem, that an update of the parent component is made from the child. I guess I could try and move the validation to the parent component but that would leave me with duplicated code since the child components are used in more than one place in the application.

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`Login`) while rendering a different component (`EmailInput`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `EmailInput`,
```

Admittedly my experience with React.js and React Native is minimal so explaining the problem might be subpar so if further information is required do not hesitate to ask. Any suggestions that can remove these warnings is highly appreciated and welcome.

Below are code snippets of the child and parent component as a reference based on feedback comment.
Thank you in advance!

Parent:

```
const Login: () => React$Node = props => {
  const [isEmailValid, setIsEmailValid] = useState(false);
  const [isPasswordValid, setIsPasswordValid] = useState(false);

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '',
    isActivityIndicatorVisible: false,
    count: 0,
    emailIsValid: false,
    passwordIsValid: false,
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      const {route} = props;

      // if (route.params && route.params.forceUpdate) {
      // props.navigation.setParams({ forceUpdate: null });
      setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        count: ++state.count,
      }));
      // }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [props.route.params]);

  const handlePressForgotPasswordButton = () => {
    resetState();
    props.navigation.navigate(Routes.SEND_CODE);
  };

  const handlePressRegisterButton = () => {
    resetState();
    props.navigation.navigate(Routes.REGISTER);
  };

  const handlePressLoginButton = () => {
    const {email, password} = state;

    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      isActivityIndicatorVisible: true,
    }));
<API CALL REMOVED FOR SPACE>
  };

  const handleChangeInput = (key, e) => {
    const {text} = e.nativeEvent;

    setState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [key]: text,
    }));
  };

  const handlePressPolicy = () => {
    props.navigation.navigate(Routes.POLICY);
  };

  const handlePressAbout = () => {
    props.navigation.navigate(Routes.ABOUT);
  };

  const resetState = () => {
    setState({
      email: '',
      password: '',
      isActivityIndicatorVisible: false,
      count: 0,
    });
  };

  return (
    <QueryRenderer
      environment={environment}
      query={LoginQuery}
      variables={{
        filter: {
          where: {},
          include: [{relation: 'userBaseline'}],
        },
        count: state.count,
      }}
      render={({error, props: relayProps}) => {
        if (!error && !relayProps) {
          return (
            <ActivityIndicator style={styles.activityIndicator} size="large" />
          );
        }

        if (relayProps) {
          const {viewer} = relayProps;

          if (viewer) {
            if (
              viewer.userBaseline &&
              viewer.userBaseline.onboardingCompleted
            ) {
              props.navigation.navigate(Routes.MAIN);
            } else {
              props.navigation.navigate(Routes.ONBOARDING_STEP1);
            }

            return (
              <ActivityIndicator
                style={styles.activityIndicator}
                size="large"
              />
            );
          }

          return (
            <LoginLayout>
              <Image
                source={Images.IMAGE_LOGIN_BACKGROUND}
                style={styles.backgroundImage}
              />
              <View style={styles.root}>
                <Image source={Images.IMAGE_LOGO} style={styles.logo} />
                <View style={styles.content}>
                  <View style={styles.contentSection}>
                    <EmailInput
                      value={state.email}
                      color={Colors.COLOR_PURPLE_DARK}
                      backgroundColor={Colors.COLOR_WHITE}
                      placeholder={i18n.t('E-mail')}
                      placeholderColor={Colors.COLOR_PURPLE_DARK}
                      onChange={e => handleChangeInput('email', e)}
                      notifyIfEmailIsValid={e => setIsEmailValid(e)}
                    />

                    <PasswordInput
                      value={state.password}
                      secureTextEntry={true}
                      password={true}
                      color={Colors.COLOR_PURPLE_DARK}
                      backgroundColor={Colors.COLOR_WHITE}
                      placeholder={i18n.t('Password')}
                      placeholderColor={Colors.COLOR_PURPLE_DARK}
                      onChange={e => handleChangeInput('password', e)}
                      notifyIfPasswordIsValid={e => setIsPasswordValid(e)}
                    />
                    <YellowGradientButton
                      disabled={
                        isEmailValid === false || isPasswordValid === false
                      }
                      onPress={handlePressLoginButton}
                      style={{marginTop: 16}}>
                      {i18n.t('Log in')}
                    </YellowGradientButton>
                    <TransparentButton
                      onPress={handlePressForgotPasswordButton}>
                      <WhiteText>{i18n.t('Forgot password?')}</WhiteText>
                    </TransparentButton>
                  </View>
                  <View style={styles.contentSection}>
                    <PurpleGradientButton onPress={handlePressRegisterButton}>
                      {i18n.t('Register')}
                    </PurpleGradientButton>
                    <TransparentButton
                      marginBottom={10}
                      onPress={handlePressAbout}>
                      <WhiteText>{i18n.t('About')}</WhiteText>
                    </TransparentButton>
                    <TransparentButton
                      marginBottom={20}
                      onPress={handlePressPolicy}>
                      <WhiteText>
                        {i18n.t('Terms, Policy & Information Security')}
                      </WhiteText>
                    </TransparentButton>
                  </View>
                </View>
              </View>
              <FullScreenActivityIndicator
                visible={state.isActivityIndicatorVisible}
                opacity={0.1}
              />
            </LoginLayout>
          );
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Child:

```
const EmailInput = props => {
  const isValidEmail = email =>
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
    /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(
      email,
    );
  const isEmailValid = () => {
    if (props.value != '') {
      var isValid = isValidEmail(props.value);
      props.notifyIfEmailIsValid(isValid);
      return isValid;
    } else {
      // parent component will consider empty value as not valid
      props.notifyIfEmailIsValid(false);
      // this component will treat empty value as valid, and do not show error message
      return true;
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.inputFieldStyles}>
      <TextInput
        style={{
          ...styles.textInput,
          ...props.style,
          width: props.width || Dimensions.DIMENSION_100_PERCENT,
          backgroundColor: Colors.COLOR_TRANSPARENT,
          color: props.color || Colors.COLOR_WHITE,
          borderColor: Colors.COLOR_WHITE,
        }}
        theme={{
          colors: {
            placeholder: 'white',
            text: 'white',
            primary: 'white',
            underlineColor: 'transparent',
            background: '#003489',
          },
        }}
        keyboardType="email-address"
        value={props.value}
        onChange={props.onChange}
        onChangeText={props.onChangeText}
        label={props.placeholder}
        underlineColor={Colors.COLOR_WHITE}
        autoCapitalize="none"
        returnKeyType={'done'}
        blurOnSubmit={true}
      />
      <HelperText
        type="error"
        visible={!isEmailValid()}
        style={styles.errorTextStyles}>
        {i18n.t('malformed_email')}
      </HelperText>
    </View>
  );
};

export default EmailInput;
```

Comment: You should post your parent and child component to let us help you